# How do I separate strings based on multiple delimiters in C?

Tags: c, string, extract

I have input of the form `(first_string*second_string)` where `*` can be one of three characters, `x`, `y` or `z`. I need to extract `first_string` and `second_string` as strings of their own.

I'm able to do this with `strchr` if `*` was always the same, but I'm not sure how to do this when `*` is one of three possible characters.

I'm assuming I need to use a function of the form

```
int star(char g) {
    if (g == 'x' || g == 'y' || g == 'z') {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Without special function, iterate the string, find the index of special character, then just slice the string at that index.

Comment: If the strings may contain the same character that separates them, it's impossible to know where they are split.

Comment: The question is strange. The title say `How do I find two strings between characters in C` but the code search for a delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strpbrk()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strpbrk.3.html) instead of `strchr()`.

Example

```
char *found;
if ((found = strpbrk(source, "xyz")) != NULL)
{
    // `found' now points to one of `x' or `y' or `z' in `source'
}
```

an obvious flaw is if the "*strings*" contain these characters.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do the task. For example you can use standard C function `strtok` declared in header `<string.h>`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "first_stringxsecond_string";

    const char *delimiters = "xyz";

    char *p = strtok( s, delimiters );

    while ( p )
    {
        puts( p );
        p = strtok( NULL, delimiters );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
first_string
second_string
```

Take into account that function strtok changes the original string by inserting the terminating zero. So you may not apply the function for string literals.

When you may not change the original string you should consider other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `star()` function definition

```
char *ptr;
if(star(g))
{
    ptr = strchr(s, g);

    if(ptr)
        *ptr = '\0';  
    printf("First string = %s\n", s);

    if(ptr)
        printf("Second string = %s\n", ptr + 1);
}
```

Comment: If `p` points to the end of the last substring, your solution produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @CareyGregory If we have delimiter at the end i.e. "foox" then  `ptr` will point to `x` and `ptr+1` will point to `\0`. So I don't see why *undefined behavior*?

Comment: And if there is no delimiter at the end? (ie, "foo" not "foox"). Bad input shouldn't cause your program to crash.

Comment: @CareyGregory I still don't get it. If there's no delimiter then that means there's only one string and no second string to separate. `ptr` will be `NULL` and only first string will get printed.